# Creating a string that calls a variable

Tags: bash

I could use some suggestions, this probably isn't the most elegant way to do this but it's what came to mind.  Let me add a couple snippets for clarity.

```
week1="01-\(04\|05\|06\|07\|08\|09\|10\)-2016"
week2="01-\(11\|12\|13\|14\|15\|16\|17\)-2016"
week3="01-\(18\|19\|20\|21\|22\|23\|24\)-2016"
week4="01-\(25\|26\|27\|28\|29\|30\|31\)-2016"
week5="02-\(01\|02\|03\|04\|05\|06\|07\)-2016"
```

I have a text file that has dates in each line, for example

```
293232343;01-02-2016;blah;more blah
234872348;02-01-2016;blah;extra blah
```

I am trying to create a loop so I can grab different data depending on the calendar week.

```
current_week=`date +%W`
for (( c=1; c<=$current_week; c++ ))
   do 
       sort -k2 archive.txt|tr "\\t" ";"|grep $week$c|while read line; do
```

My problem is that $week$c doesn't actually translate to $week1, $week2, etc.  Any easy solutions here?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point, a level
>   of
>          variable indirection is introduced.  Bash uses the value of  the  vari-
>          able  formed  from  the  rest of parameter as the name of the variable;
>          this variable is then expanded and that value is used in  the  rest  of
>          the  substitution,  rather than the value of parameter itself.  This is
>          known as indirect expansion.  The exceptions to this are the expansions
>          of  ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below.  The exclamation point
>          must immediately follow the left brace in order to  introduce  indirec-
>          tion.

Then, what you need is

```
var="week$c" 
... grep "${!var}" ...
```

Comment: I have never used that before, thank you so very much for that!